# Why the 'natural' consistency proof of PA cannot be carried out $\textbf{in}$ PA

Tags: foundations, proof-theory, incompleteness, meta-math, provability

In my proof theory monograph there is this exercise:

"The natural proof of PA cannot be carried out in PA. Why?
(This proof consists in showing that all theorems of PA are ture.)"

Apparently, by 'natural' proof he means that we accept the (usual) interpretations of the axioms of PA to be true statements and that the rules of the predicate calculus preserve truth (if one likes to consider this a proof).

Isn't the answer simply exactly the second incompleteness theorem? 
It seemed too easy so I wondered whether there was more to it..

Thanks,
Ettore

Here's a link to the question on overflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319417/why-the-natural-consistency-proof-of-pa-cannot-be-carried-out-textbfin-pa

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not sure what you mean by "consider the axioms of PA to mean true statements", because the axioms of PA are something very concrete and explicit, whereas "true statements" (even if taken as "true in $\Bbb N$") is something not very explicit, in the sense that it is not definable in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you. English is not my native tongue. I hope I improved now.

Comment: I don't think the second incompleteness theorem is the answer to that question. The theorem tells you that, if you attempt to formalize the natural proof in PA, something must go wrong. But it doesn't tell you what goes wrong. Where does the "formalized natural proof" break down? I think that's the intended question.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396084/why-isnt-this-a-truth-predicate

Comment: @Andreas: Good idea! Thanks..I haven't really a clue how to answer it though...however, one way to think about it could be that the above mentioned 'natural' proof speaks of true statements, so, in that sense, one would need not only a truth predicate, but also some formal proofs involving it. All this doesn't seem a serious argument though, a bit handwavy I guess.

Comment: @Ettore Yes, the natural proof presupposes a truth predicate and some facts about it. And by Tarski's theorem, no truth predicate for arithmetical sentences can be defined in the language of arithmetic --- not even if the only property you require is that a sentence X and the sentence "X is not true" can't hold simultaneously.

Comment: I guess that's the solution then: Tarski's theorem: We have no sufficient truth predicate, hence PA can't even say 'all theorems are true'. Even if we had and would have formal proofs in PA where PA proofs it's axioms to be true, and proofs its rules to preserve truth, I don't see how PA would finally proof 'all my theorems are true', from that.

Comment: @Ettore "Even if we had and would have formal proofs in $\mathsf{PA}$ where $\mathsf{PA}$ proofs it's axioms to be true, and proofs its rules to preserve truth, I don't see how $\mathsf{PA}$ would finally proof 'all my theorems are true', from that." This would just be an induction on proof complexity: reasoning in $\mathsf{PA}$, consider the shortest proof of a false theorem. Indeed, consider the theory $\mathsf{PA}^+$ consisting of $(i)$ the usual axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$, $(ii)$ the induction scheme extended to formulas involving a new unary predicate $True$, and (cont'd)

Comment: $(iii)$ appropriate axioms saying that $True$ holds of the axioms in $\mathsf{PA}$ and is a truth predicate for sentences in the original language of $\mathsf{PA}$. Then $\mathsf{PA}^+$ proves that every $\mathsf{PA}$-theorem is true. (Note that while truth is not definable, **being a truth predicate** *is* definable; the Tarskian truth definition gives in some sense an "implicit definition" of truth, just not an actual outright definition of truth.)